# Javascript/Jquery - Menu bar attach to side of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please can someone point me in the right direction on how to attach a menu bar to the right hand side of a IE window?

Comment: you are in a wrong place to ask for the right direction.

Comment: "attach" ? `position:fixed; right:0;` as style="..." or css class.

Comment: Yes, but has i move done the screen I would like to menu to follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS question really. JF it's response is right with poisition:fixed it will follow as you scroll.

Try putting this into a html file for a more visual approach

```
   <html>
<head>

</head>
<body style="height:2000px;">
<div style="position:fixed; right:0px; width:100px; height:200px; top:100px; background-color:blue;"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But i need JS to move the menu down as the user scrolls, something like:  
window.onscroll = function () {
i=document.body.scrollTop+50;
$("#menu-wrapper").css({top: i});

}

Comment: Sorry, but still no joy, my CSS is #menu-wrapper {position:fixed; right:0px; width:100px; height:200px; top:100px; }

Comment: <div id="menu-wrapper">
<ul id="menu">
<li><div class="menuItem"><a href="#" >About</a></div> </li>

  <li><div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Device Issuing</a></div> </li><li><div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Emergency</a></div> </li>

</ul>
 </div>

Comment: The menu will stay where it is if the position is fixed, if the user scrolls down the page, the menu will stay FIXED on the page in the same position. Do you mean you want it to move up and down using the scroll button on the mouse?

Comment: Yes I want the menu to move with me when scrolling?

Comment: it does take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Ya5ZL/